# How to filter TwitterInputDStream results by user

Tags: scala, twitter, apache-spark, streaming

I'm trying to make a Scala + Spark application that specifically listens for tweets from specific users that I define in my filters array. Currently, editing the filters array only changes the text of the tweet that it is receiving. I want to do this, except for users.

I was originally using

```
    val statuses = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None, filter)
```

To get my stream, however, in another post, it reccomended using TwitterInputDStream. I just implemented that, but I don't get how to filter based on users.

Any help is MUCH appreciated, as this is something I've struggled with for quite a while.

My code thus far:

```
val config = new twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder()
  .setOAuthConsumerKey("2pzru6Cd8aRumYHUumoCiKwYS")
    .setOAuthConsumerSecret("rKKQfISDzk715OOKS7wvGkSKdkqGsLFOdTrZ9QdJOfAjMXekNB")
    .setOAuthAccessToken("962554652-SU0aBc8Iyukka1gFJQY9Ux5XczDXSgczRpuih3ml")
    .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("k0DWDIGeJ6u2ijYJeIv6dfCuCmTPIZT8xPJ5AG4P9PV72")
    .build
val twitter_auth = new TwitterFactory(config)
val a = new OAuthAuthorization(config)
val atwitter = twitter_auth.getInstance(a).getAuthorization()
//val auth = new Option[Authorization] {}
val auth = Option(atwitter)

val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Main2")
  .setMaster("local[4]")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))
val test = new StorageLevel()

val twitter = new TwitterInputDStream(ssc, auth, filters, test )
val rec = twitter.getReceiver()
twitter.print()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Still havn't found a solution. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have a similar need - configure the language of the tweets to subscribe to. It seems the class `TwitterInputDStream` does not allow you to pass other configuration than the keywords to track. I am considering implementing a new `DStream` encapsulating Twitter4j's `TwitterStream` instead of using this one.